# Expand only the first element of a recursive accordion/tree control in Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, recursion, treeview, accordion

I'm building a recursive accordion/tree control using the following Angular code but I'm unable to find a way to expand just the first element...

```
angular.module('angular-accordion', [])
        .directive('accordionGroup', function() {
            return {
                restrict: 'E',
                replace: true,
                scope: { group: '=' },
                template: '<ul class="accordion-group"> \
                                <accordion-key ng-repeat=\'key in group\' key=\'key\'></accordion-key> \
                            </ul>'
            }
        })
        .directive('accordionKey', function($compile) {
            return {
                restrict: 'E',
                replace: true,
                scope: {key: '='},
                template: '<li ng-show=!collapsed class="accordion-key"> \
                                <div class="accordion-group-header"> \
                                    {{key.value}} \
                                </div> \
                            </li>',
                link: function(scope, element, attrs) {

                    scope.collapsed = false

                    var groupTemplate = '<accordion-group group="key.items"></accordion-group>'
                    if(angular.isArray(scope.key.items)) {
                        $compile(groupTemplate)(scope, function(cloned, scope) { element.append(cloned) })
                    }
                }
            }
        })
```

Tips?

Comment: You don't have the logic like `ng-click=switch()` to switch between accordion.

Comment: @Joy That is secondary, I need to be able to do expand/collapse behavior manually before adding interactivity.

Comment: You need to set $index or $first as attribute to accordion-key element. Use one-way binding within the link function of accordionKey. And if $first then set scope.collapse to true. http://jsfiddle.net/s5j4u9j1/